# Hidding columns from the EditForm for my wiki site

Tags: 2013, development, content-type, wiki, edit-form

I am working on an EnterpriseWiki site collection, and when users edit the page properties as follow:-

[image]

then will get all the fields inside the EnterpriseWiki content type as follow:-

[image]

now i want to hide all the fields and only keep two values ; Title & Name, so i edit the EditForm and i add the following script:-

```
<script>

$('#formTbl tr').filter(function () 
{
return !$(".ms-standardheader", this).text().match(/Name|Title/i);
}).hide();

</script>
```

and now when users edit the wiki page properties they can only edit the name & title. but my question is what will happen to the other values such as the page content, assign to , etc.. now i test this and seems that when editing the name and title the other values will not get effected which is what i need, but not sure how did SharePoint handle this, i was affraid that hiding the other columns will set their values as null or empty if the user save the editform with only the title and name inside it ? can anyone adivce on this  ?

Comment: i think best thing is test it on test wiki page.

Comment: as i mentioned that based on my own test only the title, name , modified by and modified will be updated while the other values (the fields that have been hidden using javascript) will not get affected,, but not sure if this will always be the case???

Comment: what i believe, if you are hiding all the columns, then those value will not changes expect the modified by. what ever value exist at first will remain their.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE i am not hiding all the columns, i will only show two fields Title & Name and hide the other fields,,  my question is what will happen to the values that have been hidden... from my test seems the hidden values will not get affected which is what i am looking for,, but will this always be the case? or i can not rely on this test ? i am a bit confused.

Comment: that is what i am saying, when you hide a column, the value of that still remain same(what ever you enter 1st) expect the complex column, i.e modified by, calculated...

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE so do u have any idea how SP handle this ? i mean will SP check if the value is posted back or not before updating the wiki page, and if the value is not posted back it will not modify it ?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE i found this very critical issue with hidding the fields from the edit form, now i wrote the following script inside the edit form , to hide all the fields except the Name "<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#formTbl tr').filter(function () { return !$(".ms-standardheader", this).text().match(/Name/i); }).hide(); $('#ctl00_ctl40_g_6c7d849e_da6b_4138_be9f_b99bde542065_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ctl04_c‌​tl00_WebPartMaintenancePageLink').hide(); });</script>" . and now if I submit the editform (which only contain the Name) all the html tables inside the page body will be removed.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE i have a feeling that the script i wrote will hide the HTML table from the body ,, could this be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a .remove() instead of a .hide() the fields could (although I haven't seen it to be the case) get blanked out. You would likely see some sort of post back error in that the HTML delivered is different than what was sent, I saw this a lot when trying to modify dropdown lists.

If you hide the rows with a .hide(), the fields are still present in the markup but CSSed away via JavaScript. The fields will retain their values when saved.

Comment: i am hiding the columns using javascript using .hide (as shown in my original question), but even if i chose to .remove the fields,, their values will not get effected. but still i am afraid that this is happening by chance and maybe changed under some circumstances or if i apply some updates to the SP server ? or this is not the case ?

Comment: I would lean towards using .hide, just to be on the safe side. Ripping it out of the DOM using .remove could lead to unintended consequences that aren't really necessary.

Comment: I got your point, but will the hidden fields be posted back to the server in anyway ? i know that hidden fields will not be posted back to the server and this might depend on the browser type and version ...

Comment: jQuery hide() only sets style="display:none;" more or less. Setting the hidden attribute is not the same as display: none;

Comment: so in my case i can be sure that any hidden fields will not get effected when i submit the editform with only Name & Title included ?

Comment: Correct. Yes .hide is display:none, not visibility hidden

Comment: @PirateEric ok i got your point, but also if i use .remove() instead of .hide() , then this does not mean that i will have a problem ? .As i did another test and i use .Remove() instead of .hide() without facing any problems,, but as you said to be on the safe side i should use .hide() , is this correct ?

Comment: My preference would be to use .hide over .remove.

Comment: I tried searching the web on how SP handle the hidden fields when it update the wiki page,, but could not find any article that talks about this. now i am from .net development background , and when i hide fields from the EditForm and i submit the form the hidden values will get their defualt values or null unless i take extra care of them ,, but seems SP is smart enough not to modify any hidden data..

Comment: if you are using .hide, the fields are on the form and the values present will get saved, you are just obscuring them from the display with CSS. The values will persist

Comment: @PirateEric i found this critical issue with hidding the fields from the edit form, now i wrote the following script inside the edit form , to hide all the field except the Name "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    $('#formTbl tr').filter(function () 
    {  return !$(".ms-standardheader", this).text().match(/Name/i);
    }).hide();
$('#ctl00_ctl40_g_6c7d849e_da6b_4138_be9f_b99bde542065_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_WebPartMaintenancePageLink').hide();
});</script>" . and now if I submit the editform  (which only contain the Name) all the html tables inside the page body will be removed.

Comment: @PirateEric could the script i wrote cause the HTML table to be removed from the page content ?

Comment: Possibly yes, I'd try a different selector

Comment: so i do not want to have this risk ,, could creating custom edit form that only include the Name field a better approach to follow ? rather than relying on javascript to hide/show the fields ?

Comment: honestly i'd just hide the fields in the content type and then edit the values in datasheet view if thats your end goal. no script or customizations

Comment: but if i hide the fields from the content type, then this will affect other areas. for example if you want to compare the page history for a wiki page, then all the hidden fields will not be included in the comparison ,,, this will have a domino effect on other functionalities..

Comment: @PirateEric so what do u think

Comment: Missing metadata around a wiki page doesnt really concern me, it is the content that is important in the version history

Comment: @PirateEric seems all the things are linked together,, so if i hide the fields using javascript this might hide some content (as it hide the html tables from the Page content),, at the same time hiding the fields from the content type page will remove them from the comparison  inside the page history... now i created a custom Editform but i was surprised that the Name field which i want, is not included in the edit form and i could not find a way to include it ..

Comment: @PirateEric as i was thinking of creating a new edit form ,, then edit its markup by adding style="Display:none" for all the fields except the name ,,, but creating a new edit form will not inlcude the name !!!

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box columns as well as columns with default values set will not get affected.

For example Out of the box columns like Created, Modified, Created By, Modified By will get populated automatically.

All custom fields which don't have default value set will store Blank values.

Comment: but based on my test the custom columns that have been hidden will not get affected ,,, and only the title and name in addition to the modified by and modified will be updated...

Comment: Yes custom column might have default values set.

Comment: no my custom columns do not have defualt values , and when i hide them using javascript their values did not changed, but not sure if this will always be the case ?? or might be changed on certain scenarios ?